# How to consume Kafka events with backpressure per topic/partition

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer for multiple topics (pattern based consumer). Processing of topics is similar but could, depending on correspondent configuration, have different owners and flows
I'd like to have backpressure per topic and to suspend (temporarily) consumption for some of them (if there are temporarily problems with processing).

I thought to do something like:

- set *ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG* to some descent value in order to  have backpressure per partition (hence per topic).
- before every poll (explicit poll will be used - no auto-commit) I check (for each topic) if there are unprocessed events and if so - pause it with *KafkaConsumer.pause*. In contrary - if all paused topic's messages are processed resume it with *KafkaConsumer.resume*.

There are, however, few uncertainties regarding this approach:

- First of all - does it looks like a working solution? Isn't there better / standard solution? It seems to me like a common usecase.
- Is pause/resume lightweight operation (i.e. client only, not sending anything to broker)? From looking up in kafka code it seems so, but ...
- If there are fetched for partition but not polled events for a topic could the next poll fetch again for that partition, thus fetching more then limit? In code it seems such fetches are kept as *Fetcher.completedFetches* and are excluded from next fetch. But again - but based just on quick look.
- If there are completed fetches but not polled, and the partition is reassigned - would the completed fetch be garbage collected? In code I see that they are cleaned only on subscribe / unsubscribe / assign? So, here probably the answer is - no.
- And after all, event if this works because of current implementation I use, is there any official specification / documentation that could assure that this is not just an implementation behavior and will stay on?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing out of the box in Kafka for Backpressure but the frameworks likes Akka's [Alpakka Kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#back-pressure-explained) does.

And they contributed a lot to Kafka's [code base](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/alpakka-kafka-flow-control-optimizations) that it work efficiently.

If you want to you need example implementation should look like, I have to blogs about it, [blog1](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/alpakka-kafka-stream-and-akka-finite-state-machine/), [blog2](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/)